# Xamarin messaging by Websockets SignalR

Tags: xamarin, websocket, signalr

SignalR for Xamarin doesn't have way to work through Websockets.

I have a web service with messaging by SygnalR by websockets.

Can i receive message in Xamarin without implementing SignalR to Xamarin?

Is it important to have SignalR on Xamarin client side?

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented a SignalR hub in your sever, you can use SignalR Client nuget in Xamarin. The transport will be SSE (Server Sent Events) by default, but it works pretty well.

Implementing a websocket in the client just to connect to a SignalR server makes no sense at all, unless you really need to use WebSockets instead of SSE.

Comment: It won´t work through web sockets, it will work through SSE, but it will work

Comment: Is this stil the case? Can we now use Websockets?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR uses transports to connect to the server. The portable version of SignalR client does not support the webSockets transport since there is no portable version of WebSocket client available. This is fine since there are two more transports - longPolling and serverSentEvents that can be used to talk to the server.

You can't connect to the SignalR 2.x server with bare webSockets. There is a [protocol](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) that needs to be followed and if a client does not follow this [protocol](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) its requests will be rejected.
If you absolutely need to use websockets you can implement your own websockets transport by implementing the [`IClientTransport`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Transports/IClientTransport.cs) interface and pass it to the `Start` method. This is how the webSockets transport is supported on UWP. [Here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Store/Transports) is all the code I needed to write.